# HuggingFace Summarization: effect of specifying both `do_sample` and `num_beams`

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, summarization, beam-search

I am using a HuggingFace summarization pipeline to generate summaries using a fine-tuned model. The `summarizer` object is initialised as follows:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

summarizer = pipeline(
    "summarization", 
    model=model, 
    tokenizer=tokenizer, 
    num_beams=5, 
    do_sample=True, 
    no_repeat_ngram_size=3,
    max_length=1024,
    device=0,
    batch_size=8
)
```

According to the documentation, setting `num_beams=5` means that the top 5 choices are retained when a new token in the sequence is generated based on a language model, and the model moves forward discarding all other possibilities, and repeating this after every new token is generated. However, this option seems to be apparently incompatible with `do_sample=True` which seems to activate a behaviour where new tokens are picked based on some random strategy (which doesn't have to be uniformly random of course, but I don't know the details of this process). Could anyone explain clearly how  `num_beams=5` and `do_sample=True` would work together (no error is raised so I assume this is a valid `summarizer` configuration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First difference is that temperature is applied to the logits.

The second difference is that instead of taking the top token of the beam per beam, the choice of the beam is sampled from the distribution of that beam:

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/generation_utils.py#L2626

I believe the rest stays the same, but you can continue to read the code to be 100% sure

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say "First difference is that temperature is applied to the logits", could you clarify the difference between which case and which case? Are you saying that the temperature is applied to the logits if you set `do_sample=True` but applied not if you set `do_sample=False`? Note that I never specify the temperature, so are you saying the code uses different temperature values depending on whether I do the sampling or not?

Comment: yes, it is only applied in the case of do_sample. temperature doesn't affect the ordering of the logits, so applying it to regular beam search wouldn't change anything

Comment: I'm saying you could specify a temperature if you are using sampled beam search, to increase the diversity (by flattening the distribution) or reducing it a bit (by making it more peaky). Temperature is a constant multiplication factor applied to each logits before softmax, to modify the flatness of the logits

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly what you're saying, this means that if I do not set a temperature (or set a temperature equal to 1), and I set beam size > 1 (for example 5), then `do_sample` wouldn't make any difference whether true or false. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: no. it samples from the probabilities of each beam instead of taking the armax, before comparing the probability of the beams